# Geolocation Builder----Web Experience Factory

Tags: builder

I have one page.i have to Add Geolocation Builder to this Particular Page.
There is Client Type And another is the Server Type.So How to use this One in
Web Experience Factory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Web Experience Factory (WEF) Wiki has samples of mobile web applications, including one that leverages the geolocation builder):

http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/pfwiki.nsf/dx/Developing_Web_Wpplications_for_Smartphones_and_Tablets_with_IBM_Web_Experience_Factory

The particular input you're asking about determines whether an action is called on the "server" (via AJAX request) when the HTML5 page on the device determines the location, or whether it only calls a Javascript function ( "client" ).

I hope that info helps,
..Mike Burati 
The postings on this site are my own and do not necessarily represent the positions, strategies, or opinions of IBM.